# Retrieve type arguments information of inherited traits from Type

Tags: scala, types, type-inference

I can easily extract the type information of a `PartialFunction` Type by inspecting its `typeArgs` member:

```
scala> typeOf[PartialFunction[String,Int]].typeArgs
res168: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = List(String, Int)
```

However, if I combine `PartialFunction` with another trait, it seems I have lost the ability to retrieve the type arguments of the `PartialFunction` trait:

```
scala> val t = typeOf[Iterable[Any] with PartialFunction[String,Int]]
t: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = scala.Iterable[Any] with scala.PartialFunction[String,Int]

scala> t.typeArgs
res170: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = List()
```

It appears that `t` retains that `List(String, Int)` information, as it retains the information that it is `with PartialFunction[String,Int]`, but I can no longer see a way to extract that information about the type.

How can I retrieve the `PartialFunction` type arguments of a type `SomeTrait with PartialFunction[String,Int]`?

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

```
t.baseType(typeOf[PartialFunction[_,_]].typeSymbol).typeArgs
```

## Explanation

You can inspect the base classes in the inheritance chain via the `baseClasses` member:

```
scala> t.baseClasses
res181: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] =
  List(<refinement of scala.Iterable[Any] with String => Int>,
  trait PartialFunction,
  ...)
```

You can retrieve the `Symbol` representing `PartialFunction` from there, and use it to get the `PartialFunction` instance of `t` via the [baseType method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0-M4/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/api/Types$Type.html#baseType(clazz:Types.this.Symbol):Types.this.Type).

```
scala> val pf = t.baseType(t.baseClasses(1))
pf: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = PartialFunction[String,Int]
```

Now you can inspect the type arguments of that `PartialFunction` as per normal:

```
scala> pf.typeArgs
res192: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = List(String, Int)
```

If you know the trait type that you want to access, it would be safer to reference it specifically rather than pulling it from the base classes collection:

```
scala> t.baseType(typeOf[PartialFunction[_,_]].typeSymbol).typeArgs
res202: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = List(String, Int)
```